# Keep context menu open after user clicks checkbox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have also asked this question [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/Ithf1UtF614/zbmfxax93EUJ) at the chromium Google group.

I would like to be able to keep a context menu open even after a user checks, or unchecks, a checkbox. My plugin allows users to check which devices they are using when testing and when testing multiple devices, it is frustrating to open the context menu several times to tick each device.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? It does not seem to be supported natively. I don't really want to use some magic to re-open the menu, if possible, after a user checks a given device, hence the question here. If it is the best (yet hacky) way, then fair enough. I hope it's not! I think menu flickering would also look bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing in [the API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) to allow that.

It might be an interesting feature request - if you're willing to spend time to formulate it at https://crbug.com/

Comment: Well, thanks for clearing that up Xan. I have now made a feature request for it which is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489660). If it gets implemented I'll post an answer here too.

Comment: I opened a [new issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202512) to discuss this.